# Stop at breakpoints in the fragment

Tags: android, debugging, android-fragments, android-studio

I'm rather new with android studio, but faced such problems: code has stop on breakpoints in main activity, but has skipped it in fragment. I've read that debugging of fragment is possible with fragment manager in logcat, but I find such method inconvenient. 
Is there any way to stop at breakpoints in the fragment while debugging in android studio?

Comment: yes put a breakpoint in oncreate/oncreateview of your fragment

Comment: @Bhargav but i need not only debug onCreate, but also some methods in fragment, for example onClick for button or checkbox, as well as what this functions call further (like making list to show or anything else, don't matter). I still can't stop on breakpoints in fragment if it is no onCreate.

Comment: that means the onclick listeners are not being set.

Comment: @Bhargav they are set and working! I just want to see current values in code.

Comment: well in the places that u set the break points inside the red dot do you see a cross mark or a tick mark? I ask this because setting break points on statements like `Drawable d;` don't actually work when that happens you will see a cross mark inside the red dot of the breakpoint

Comment: @Bhargav no, it's normal breakpoints. They stopped in this places when they were called from activity.

Comment: but your question is about the execution not stopping at those places yes?

Comment: Yes, and I still didn't figure out why(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was funny, but after android studio update everything began working as it should!